# Does anyone know an existing magnet like this?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have an idea and it would involve two magnetic strips. these strips would lock together in parallel to keep something closed. then, when they open, they would bend in the middle only (maybe on a hinge), and then lock in place. the natural state would want to be in the open state. The magnetic form would be keeping them locked in parallel. When "open" the hinge in the center of the magnet strip would open to about 90 degrees. this would make a box shape opening with the magnetic strips.

Is there anything like this that exists? I know there are magnetic strips that lock together in parallel. (what are they called?), i just don't know if they can then also lock open when no longer in magnetic range[image: magnetic clips]